# Conection D-Link router to Ubuntu

Tags: d-link

Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit
D-Link router DSL-2750 U

I have this router ADSL connected to a PC with Ubuntu 16.04 OS.
I want also to have a wireless connection but the PC don’t have wireless adapter.
The router is wireless, connect to the PC can it be used as wireless adapter?.
If it can how to make this connection because Ubuntu doesn't detect this connection
Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To clarify : you want to use your router as a WiFi card ?

The D-Link DSLRouter can not do that and it is not supported by dd-wrt, an alternate router firmware which could.